# ios - AVAudioPlayer - audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying is sometimes called at random times in a clip

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer

I have a ~30 minute mp3 file being played by an AVAudioPlayer.  Sometimes, `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully` is called (with the successfully flag set to TRUE), even when it is only 5 minutes into the clip. It happens infrequently, but it can happen at any position in the clip.

I've only noticed that it happens when the user is pressing a button on the user interface, or moving a slider. And the more quickly they press buttons on the user interface, the more likely it is to happen it seems.

Any ideas what could be causing this, or how to fix it?

MORE INFO:
Only 1 sound is played at a time. No sounds are played for button actions.  The AVAudioPlayer is declared locally in my main ViewController.  I've tested on an iPhone 3GS and an iPhone 4s. The problem happens very very rarely on the iPhone 4s. It's much more frequent on the 3GS.

Comment: 1. Are you playing any other sound clips for button actions?.
2. How is AVAudioPlayer declared (Globally or Locally)?.
3. What's the device you're testing?.

Comment: If you could post your then we can help you..

Comment: @deamonsarea Only 1 sound is played at a time. No sounds are played for button actions.  The AVAudioPlayer is declared locally in my main ViewController.  I've tested on an iPhone 3GS and an iPhone 4s. The problem happens very very rarely on the iPhone 4s. It's much more frequent on the 3GS.

Comment: May be it is because of the memory. Just try to reduce the length and size of the mp3 and see. We need code for further more debugging.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had the same problem starting yesterday. Don't whether we were having the same problem but I will throw it here

In the slider ValueChanged event handler, I tried to update the view elements based on the new position of the slider. But within the updateViewMethod, I called another

```
slider.value = self.player.currentTime;
```

Removing that solved my problem.

So in short, your timer's callback should update the slider, but slider valuechanged handler should not redo the work.